# Error: 0x80073701 on windows 2012 server for enabling Hyper V

Tags: windows

I am facing "Error: 0x80073701" for enabling Hyper V on Windows server 2012 R2.

The virtualization is enabled in BIOS but still I am facing the issue.

[image: Error]

Comment: Failed to bulk stage deployment manifest and pin deployment for package:Package_557_for_KB3000850~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.8 [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING

Comment: The above log was found in CBS logs

Comment: Is this issue something related to KB3000850 service pack?

Answer (score 0):

Its trying to tell you that the file:

Package_557_for_KB3000850~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.8.cat

and or

Package_557_for_KB3000850~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.8.mum

is missing or corrupted. They should be in the Windows->servicing->packages
folder. Last time I had this kind of problem I just copied the files from
another server into that folder and all was happy after that.
There were people telling me to install the Korean language pack, but I 
didn't need to go that far. Good luck.

Comment: Can I copy all the Hyper V packages from the working server and copy to non working server?

Comment: And I don't have the KB3000850~31bf3856ad364e35 file in the working server. Any other idea?

Comment: You can download KB3000850 from the Microsoft  Update Catalog: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb3000850

Comment: but still the issue is not resolved even after copying the KB file

Comment: MS has a blog that touches on the subject: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2011/06/19/how-to-resolve-the-error-0x80073701error_sxs_assembly_missing-when-you-are-installing-a-service-pack-or-update/

Comment: Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384 [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]

Comment: The above is found in CBS log